# Redirecting the output of both stdout and stderr?

Tags: redirect

I have one program, which writes its output to stderr and it also runs a executable internally
which writes to stdout. I want to redirect the output of both to the same file using redirection operator something like "./a.out 2> output.txt", but this redirects the stderr, How to specify stdout also here.

Comment: It's a pretty good question, but it belongs on SuperUser, not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Linux:

```
./a.out > output.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Ya it works fine but if I write 1>&2, then it does not redirect. Can u explain me the meaning of this?

Comment: 1>&2 would direct stdout to stderr - see http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html for more information

Answer (score 2):

Or simply

```
./a.out &> output.txt
```